# Are the mean of samples taken from Metropolis-Hastings MCMC normally distributed?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, posterior

I've come across the following theorem while studying MCMC. It seems to suggest that the sample mean taken from the MCMC – the posterior marginal expectation – should be normally distributed, using just $\phi(x) = x$:

> **Theorem 4.4. (A Central Limit Theorem).** For a Harris recurrent, $\pi$-invariant Markov chain, and a function $\phi : \mathbb X \to \mathbb R$ satisfying enough regularity conditions,
>   $$
> \sqrt{t} \left[ \frac1t \sum_{i=1}^t \phi(X_t) - \int_{\mathbb X} \, \phi(x) \pi(x) \, dx \right] \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{t \to \infty}^D \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2(\phi))
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> \sigma^2(\phi) = \mathbb V[\phi(X_1)] + 2 \sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathbb{Cov}[\phi(X_1), \phi(X_k)]
> .$$
>   The variance and covariance in the expression above are with respect to the distribution $\pi$ of the Markov chain in its stationary regime.

I am wondering is there some extension of this result when dimension of the parameter space is larger than 1? So in this case $\phi : \mathbb X \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I've transcribed your screenshot into text, since the big page gap made reading difficult. It would also be helpful if you gave a source; I searched briefly and didn't find it.

Comment: I'd expect that a similar convergence holds: taking $\phi_i(x) = x^T e_i$ for each vector in a basis $\{e_i\}$, for example, shows that all one-dimensional projections become normal, I believe uniformly across the different $\phi_i$, which strongly suggests it should converge to multivariate normal. In a few minutes of looking I didn't find such a theorem, though.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I found this lecture notes here, the chapter 4 link. https://sites.google.com/site/pierrejacob/advanced-simulation

Comment: The ergodic average is asymptotically normal, this is simply the central limit theorem. Which also works in larger dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed when the univariate Markov chain central limit theorem holds, the multivariate CLT also holds. In fact, the the univariate CLT is a consequence of the multivariate CLT via the Cramer-Wold Theorem. Look at Page 7-9 [here](http://www.mcmchandbook.net/HandbookChapter1.pdf).

However, the Theorem 4.4 you indicated has the hidden line of "satisfying enough regularity conditions". These regularity conditions are difficult to verify but do hold in general. These conditions are that of the rate of convergence of the Markov chain to its stationary distribution. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409112v2.pdf) summarizes most of the research done in this field. For the Metropolis-Hasting MCMC (which is reversible), you need that the chain be *geometrically ergodic* with a finite 2nd moment.

If these conditions hold true, the the multivariate CLT takes the following form: If $\phi: \mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and $E_{\pi} \|\phi(X_1) \|^2 <\infty$ and $\{X_i\}$ is geometrically ergodic, then there exists a $n \times n$ positive definite matrix, $\Sigma$ such that,
$$\sqrt{t} \left[\dfrac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t{ \phi(X_i)} - \int_\mathbb{X} \phi(x) \pi(x) \right] \to N_n(0, \Sigma), $$

where if $\phi(X_t) = Y_t = (Y^{(1)}_t, Y^{(2)}_t, \dots, Y^{(n)}_t)$, then the $(i,j)th$ entry of $\Sigma$ is

$$ \Sigma_{ij} = Cov_{\pi}(Y^{(i)}_1, Y^{(j)}_1) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} Cov_{\pi}(Y^{(i)}_1, Y^{(j)}_{1+k}). $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have two question. 

1. In practice we wait for the chain to run for some time and then start to take samples. Say the first sample I take is from $X_k$ where k = 50. Can I replace the X_1 with X_50 in the variance function?

Comment: Second question. Could you specify what the dimension of $Var_\pi \phi(X_1)$ and $Cov_\pi(\phi(X_1),\phi(X_{1+k})$

Comment: Yes. The statement of the CLT says that this holds true _regardless_ of the starting value. This is the reason that there is also a school of thought that says there is no need to throw away initial samples. Second question: The matrics $Var_{\pi}\phi(X_1)$ and $Cov_{\pi}(\phi(X_1), \phi(X_{1+k}))$ $n\times n$ matrices. The Var matrix is positive definite, but the infinite sum of the covariances might not be positive definite.

Comment: Huh interesting. So even if I throw away, say first 50 initial samples, the infinit sum of $cov(\phi(X_{50}),\phi(X_{50+k})$ will not be much smaller than $cov(\phi(X_1),\phi(X_{1+k})$? I understand that there is the infinite sum, but I thought if the chain converges, say after 50 iterations, then $cov(\phi(X_{50}),\phi(X_{51})) $ will definitely be smaller than $cov(\phi(X_1),\phi(X_2)) $, or there is no such result?

Comment: so is it that $Var(\phi(X_1))$ is the diagonal matrix, and the covariance matrix is in fact the cross covariance matrix? Otherwise I cannot imagine how covariance matrix of two n-dimensional variable can still be nxn

Comment: A Markov chain is a weakly dependent process, so irrespective of where it starts the covariance between consecutive samples is going to be the same. So $cov(X_{50}, X_{51}) = cov(X_{1}, X_{2})$. Which is why the infinite sum only sums over the lags. The variance matrix need not be a diagonal matrix. The variance matrix represents the variance in the distribution of $\pi$ and the covariance sum is the correlation due to the Markov chain.

Comment: I've thought about this.. Consider a random walk markov chain, $X_i = X_{i-1} + W$, where W~N(0,$\sigma^2$). Then cov(X2,X1) = cov(X1+W,X1) = var(X1). Cov(X3,X2) = cov(X2+W,X1+W) = cov(X1+2W,X1+W) = var(X1) + 2$\sigma^2$.... I apologize in advance it seems my brain is short-circuited at the moment, but appreciate it if you could point out wher eIm wrong

Comment: I am not sure what the example is meant to show there. I will say that the random walk Markov chain that you wrote down does not converge to a stationary distribution. (The example is an AR(1) process which only converges if the correlation coefficient is less 1 in absolute value). I have made an edit in  my answer, maybe that will clear things out a little bit.

Comment: I see now I understand. Thanks for your input. Can I just be curious why this result is mentioned less than the univaraite one? After all, it is much more common for the bayesian model we are interested to include more than one parameter, right?

Comment: I am on the same page with you on that one. I think it is because there has been astonishingly little interest in estimating the univariate/multivariate variance/covariance in MCMC since the algorithms are as it is pretty complex. People have been way too invested in diagnosing the convergence of the Markov chain, than actually assessing quality of estimation. However, recently there has been work done in estimating $\Sigma$, and hopefully we will see this continue to grow. Try looking at the R package 'mcmcse'.

Comment: Wald should probably be Wold.